# Reposition a VLC window programmatically

Tags: c#, python, windows, cross-platform, vlc

I'm sure others have run into this problem too...

I often watch videos in a small VLC window while working on other tasks, but no matter where the window is placed, I eventually need to access something in the GUI behind it, and have to manually reposition the video window first.

This could be solved by having the VLC window snap to another corner whenever the mouse pointer is moved over it. I haven't found an app that does this, so would like to write one. What technologies could I use to do this? Cross platform might be harder... so what if just on Windows?

I'd prefer something in C# (or Python), but am willing to learn something new if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a windows only solution. You dont need to actually put the mouse over the window. All you need to do is [Find the window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499(VS.85).aspx) using its name and [send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(VS.85).aspx) WM_MOVE. I dont know the name of the window which VLC uses. You could use Spy++ to find its name.

Comment: The point *was* that a mouse movement over the VLC window triggers moving the window. The whole idea is that you can then access what was behind the window. Having the window wander around endlessly might work too (but would be annoying as hell :-)) but triggering it when moving the mouse over the window is actually a nice way to do it (and has nothing to do with difficulties in finding the window in the first place). http://timesnapper.com/NextAction/ does this too, if you want to know how it looks :-)

Comment: @Johannes. The Timesnapper behaviour is exactly what I mean

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit OOT, but in Windows 7, shaking the active window will hide others to reveal the desktop (and so will clicking/hovering the rightmost taskbar button). Instead of hiding/moving vlc, you could just temporarily reveal the whole desktop. Shaking the active window again brings everything back.